# How to get month name in string on JMonthChooser from JCalendar

Tags: java, swing, date, jcalendar

How to get month name in string on `JMonthChooser` from `JCalendar` (toedter.com/jcalendar/) and convert it to string "01", "02","03",...,"12" as simple as using `SimpleDateFormat`.

I'll try :

```
String mymonth;
SimpleDateFormat sdfm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
JComboBox combom = (JComboBox)jMonthChooser1.getSpinner();
mymonth = sdfm.format(((JTextField)combom.getEditor()).getText());
```

But no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the other way that what I need :
Here are the code :

```
JCalendar jCalendar1 = new JCalendar();
String mymonth;
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
Date date1 = jCalendar1.getDate();
mymonth = sdf1.format(date1);
```

Comment: What happened to `JMonthChooser`?

Comment: My main goal is to find the name of the month from JCalendar and indexes in the format string "01", "02", ..., "12". I was confused, I guess using JMonthChooser earlier. But then I could get straight month and the index names used JCalendar.
The name of the month I get using:

    String mymonth;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    Date date1 = jCalendar1.getDate();
    mymonth = sdf1.format(date1);

Bantuan Anda sangat saya apresiasi. Terima kasih.

Comment: Is your desired `Locale` not supported?

Comment: Bantuan Anda  sangat saya apresiasi. Terima kasih. (I really appreciated your help @trashgod. Thank you.)

Comment: It appears to be supported [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html).

Comment: Thanks @trashgod. I'm using toedter.com/jcalendar for Netbeans, I'm still didn't find my Locale  in JCalendar properties on Netbeans. Can you help me?

Comment: Try `new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", new Locale("in", "ID"))`.

Comment: I use `jCalendar1.setLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("ID"));` in my `jCalendar1PropertyChange` for Indonesian `Locale`

Answer (score 4):

Given an instance of `JMonthChooser`, a `PropertyChangeListener` will see a new value of type `Integer` in the range `0 .. 11`. Rather than trying to coerce this to a date suitable for `SimpleDateFormat`, consider using a suitable [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

```
JMonthChooser jmc = new JMonthChooser();
jmc.addPropertyChangeListener("month", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getPropertyName() + ": "
            + String.format("%02d", ((Integer) e.getNewValue()).intValue() + 1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String month;
if(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()==0){
    month = "Jan";
}else if(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()==1){
    month = "Feb";
}else if(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()==2){
    month = "Mar";
}else if(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()==3){
    month = "Apr";
}else if(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()==4){
    month = "May";
}else if(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()==5){
    month = "Jun";
}else if(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()==6){
    month = "Jul";
}else if(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()==7){
    month = "Aug";
}else if(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()==8){
    month = "Sep";
}else if(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()==9){
    month = "Oct";
}else if(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()==10){
    month = "Nov";
}else{
    month = "Dec";
}
```